# Swift 3 preview 2 linux error: use of unresolved identifier

Tags: linux, ubuntu, swift3

Building my app on Linux get an error:

```
$ swift build 

Compile Swift Module 'finder' (1 sources)

main.swift:24:15: error: use of unresolved identifier 'URLSession' 

let session = URLSession.shared
```

---

```
$ swiftc main.swift

main.swift:24:15: error: use of unresolved identifier 'URLSession'

let session = URLSession.shared
```

It's working in XCODE 8 on my Mac.
I'm trying Swift on Ubuntu:

```
$ swift --version

Swift version 3.0 (swift-3.0-PREVIEW-2)

Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Apparently something is wrong; without seeing your code that's about it.

Comment: I *think* the "Drop the NS prefix" renaming has not yet been done for Linux, i.e. it would still be `NSURLSession`.

Comment: you might like to look into this swifty wrapper around IBM's libcurl https://github.com/dmcyk/SwiftyCurl/

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

**1:** On Linux, even up to 3.0-PREVIEW-2, the "NS" prefix hasn't been dropped in Foundation yet. You still need to use NSURLSession, rather than URLSession. This will change in Foundation with 3.0-PREVIEW-3 based on the GitHub branches.

**2:** And this is a showstopper, URLSession/NSURLSession doesn't work on Linux. It hasn't been implemented yet. If you look at the source code for URLSession right now:

https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/93d0018a0891f876065651c3ee8c63f256a38de4/Foundation/NSURLSession/NSURLSession.swift#L200

You'll see that calling `sharedSession()` returns `NSUnimplemented()`

At some point, URLSession will come to Linux - but it hasn't been implemented yet.

I believe the reason is that on OS X, URLSession for Swift simply a bridge to the Objective C implementation that already existed. On Linux, Foundation is being implemented entirely in Swift and they just haven't got around to re-writing this yet.